# Installing TeamCity on FreeBSD

Tags: installation, teamcity, freebsd

I have FreeBSD 13.0 running on my computer and I want to use it as a continuous integration server. How can I install TeamCity on it, without using a graphical interface?

Comment: So you want to install and run TeamCity from command line and you cannot use web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's just

- download TeamCity tar.gz package
- Unpack package to the desired location (`<TeamCity home>`)
- execute `<TeamCity home>/bin/runAll.sh` to start default server and build agent
- open you browser and point it to your machine, port `8111`, to accept license agreement and answer several questions regarding TeamCity configuration (select data directory location, select DB, create first user)

You should refer to the [documentaion](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server) for further information.

Comment: How can I execute the last step without a browser?

Comment: You have to accept license agreement in browser at least once (once it is accepted you can copy your data directory to reuse it)

Comment: You mean on an other computer?